# Can I re-battle the other Mega Men in any way?

Tags: mega-man-zx-advent

I can easily refight all the Pseudoroids like Bifrost, Chronoforce and Buckfire by going back to where they spawned as bosses, but is there any way to fight the other Megamen like Aeolus and Atlas? Going back to where they were doesn't work, and they're not part of the Boss Rush in the final area either.

Is there any way to fight them again or are they only once per playthrough?

Comment: You just want to fight them, or what?

Comment: @RavenDreamer basically yes, partially to practice for Hard and mostly for fun

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fight them again in Boss Survival Mode (finish the game with both characters) and Boss Battle Mode (beat Boss Survival Mode), where you can choose which boss to fight.

The difficulty for Boss Battle Mode is always set to Expert, but you will still have your two subtanks.

The Boss Survival Mode order is:

Diaburn -> Chronoforce -> Rosespark -> Condorock -> Kaisemine -> Bifrost -> Tesrat -> Argoyle & Urgoyle -> Atlas -> Siarnaq -> Thetis -> Helios -> Model ZX -> Prometheus & Pandora -> Albert.

Comment: That'll have to do, forgot about that mode (replaying after losing my 100% complete cartridge :c)